# Clipboard image to file selection dialog just like that (macOS)? ⚡️

Tags: mac

I wonder what's the fastest method in the universum to input an image from clipboard to a Choose a file dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use: 
 <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>Command</kbd>  +  <kbd>3</kbd>  to save your captured image to the download folder.

Using: Shift  +  <kbd>Command</kbd>  +  <kbd>4</kbd>  you can make a selection.

If the dada is in Clipboard you can open the clipboard viewer, select the data (could be an image or whatever), click the button **Save data** and it will be saved in a folder. Now you can access it.

Clipboard viewer image below:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how Clipboard Viewer is related to this, but what I am definitely speaking what is the quickest way to input the image you have grabbed with Ctrl+Shft+Cmd+4.

Comment: You can put it in any folder using the Clipboard viewer **Save data...** button. Remember to write the extension also.